# Insert into SQL next in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL with a column called `Credit Card Code`

Data eg

```
CCARD-000093
CCARD-000094
CCARD-000095
CCARD-000096
CCARD-000097
CCARD-000098
CCARD-000099
CCARD-000100
CCARD-000101
```

When inserting data into this table, how can I get the next value in the sequence?

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT 'CCARD-' + 
(SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ccc.CreditCardCode,7, 6) as INT)) AS 
NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM CustomerCreditCard ccc)
```

This gives `CCARD-101`

How can I get this to return `CCARD-000101` ???

Comment: Please share sequence code and what `next value for` returns.

Comment: I couldn't get the syntax for `NEXT VALUE FOR` correct, so I couldn't get it to return a value.

Comment: You better use a computed column for this data and just use a regular int identity. This way you don't have to worry about calculating the next value.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to increment the table while inserting Record you can auto increment using Identity and Presisted Concept

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TestTables', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE TestTables 
END
```

**Reset the identity from where you want to start**

```
DBCC checkident ('TestTables', reseed, 93)

CREATE TABLE TestTables
(
    CreditCard AS ('CCARD-0000' + CAST(AutoIncId as varchar)) PERSISTED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    
    [AutoIncId] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [Bank] VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO TestTables ([Bank]) VALUES ('Indus')
INSERT INTO TestTables ([Bank]) VALUES ('ICICI')
INSERT INTO TestTables ([Bank]) VALUES ('HDFC')
INSERT INTO TestTables ([Bank]) VALUES ('DBS')

SELECT * FROM TestTables
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in the context of my question? If I was to insert into the column `CreditCardCode` how would I increment that value, based off the highest current value?

Comment: if the data is inserted directly into the table then you can follow this process if you want to insert on maximum value then you need to go through MAX select @BrendanGooden i will post you

Answer (score 1):

Next value, fixed length, with leading '0':

```
SELECT 'CCARD-' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',6)+CAST(1+MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ccc.CreditCardCode,7, 6) as INT)) AS NVARCHAR(6)),6) 
FROM CustomerCreditCard ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick

```
INSERT INTO CustomerCreditCard (CustomerCode, CreditCardCode, CreditCardDescription, NameOnCard, Address, City, State, PostalCode, Country, ExpMonth, ExpYear, Telephone, Email, IsActive,  ResidenceType, UserCreated, DateCreated, UserModified, DateModified, County, StartMonth, StartYear)
  SELECT c.CustomerCode, 
    (SELECT 'CCARD-' + REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN((SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ccc.CreditCardCode,7, 6) as INT)) + 1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM CustomerCreditCard ccc))) +
(SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ccc.CreditCardCode,7, 6) as INT)) + 1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM CustomerCreditCard ccc)), 
    'Web Credit Card',
    c.CustomerName, 
    c.Address, 
    c.City, 
    c.State, 
    c.PostalCode, 
    c.Country, 
    'Jan', 
    2025, 
    c.Telephone, 
    c.Email, 
    1, 
    c.ResidenceType, 
    'webadmin', 
    GETDATE(), 
    'webadmin', 
    GETDATE(), 
    c.County, 
    'Jan',
    2010
    FROM Customer c
  WHERE c.CustomerCode = 'CUST-015056'
```